# Wireless Networks Not appearing Elementary Loki 0.4.1

Tags: wifi

(Posted on Ubuntu, they suggested I take my question here. xpost below)

Complete noob so forgive me. I'm setting up a relative's computer and we've installed Elemerntary OS (0.4.1 Loki) The kernel is 4.10.0

Issue is the wireless networks are not showing up in the network list even though we get them all appearing in windows 10

I've done some searching. The computer is a HP notebook and the wireless is Realtek RTL8723BE. Cannot connect to Wifi at all - but funnily the extention (to wifi we want) is showing up... however is continuously dropping from one bar to zero bars. We do not have access to a wired connection right now.

What do we do?

Comment: Please do a search on RTL8723BE first, I see multiple questions with seemingly similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings=>network=>wireless and turn wifi on there.
My Wifi wasn't working when launched from wingpanel.